# Water purifier not getting sand (bug)

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I am getting a bug where the dupes are not supplying a water purifier with sand (after the initial fill up). [This bug was reported back in February](https://forums.kleientertainment.com/klei-bug-tracker/oni/the-water-purifier-was-not-supplied-with-sand-r3844/). Is there any update on whether this bug has a workaround?

Comment: Three things I would check is do you have any sand in stock? Also I'd check the Duplicant's navigation path, which you can toggle from the Duplicant detail panel, to ensure that they can reach it. Lastly, make sure the pipes are not blocked, and are flowing. Otherwise Duplicant's will ignore the filter.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer on another forum. Apparently this bug is triggered when the sieve is built against a wall. If you run into this problem, try building it in a location where it has space on both sides.